# Where does the space of the relative-positioned div come from?

Tags: css

Why doesn't the relative-positioned div line up at 0,0 like the fixed-positioned div? I've tried setting padding/margin to 0, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpermethod/cWdWp/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the `div` with `position:relative` take as parent the `body`. The `body` has automatically padding of 10 pixels (in firefox, in other browsers may differ) . If you add `body {padding:0;}` will be both in the same place. To overcome "problems" like this, you can use a reset css like this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cWdWp/9/

Comment: In my browser Google 9.0.597.94, I also need to set the margin on body to 0. But then, all seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having this problem a lot you can just use Eric Meyers CSS Reset:

http://www.cssreset.com/downloads/css-resets/eric-meyer-reset-css/eric-meyer-reset.css

It reverts all standard browser styles to 0 padding and margins.

Answer (score 1):

It's the default padding on the body.  Fixed positioning ignores its container, like absolute positioning does, while relative positions you within the container. `body {padding:0;}` will fix it.